# How to use enums as a query parameter with Axum

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I have an enum similar to:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub enum Gender {
    Male,
    Female,
    NonBinary
}
```

and I a have an axum handler function which expects it to be passed in as `Query(gender): Query<Gender>`

But when I request the endpoint like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/greet?gender=Male
```

The page returns the following error message:

```
Failed to deserialize query string: invalid type: map, expected enum Gender
```

If I switch the params to use a struct instead everything works fine, which is why I know this is specifically an issue with enum serialization.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Please include a [mre] if you want debugging help.

Comment: According to your error message, this might work: `http://localhost:3000/greet?Male`. But I agree with @cafce25, this entire discussion is pretty pointless if you don't show us the actual code that processes the URL parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a struct as your query parameter type:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub enum Gender {
    Male,
    Female,
    NonBinary
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct GreetParams {
    gender: Gender,
}

async fn greet_handler(Query(params): Query<GreetParams>) {}
```

The reason you get an error is because `?gender=Male` is parsed as a mapping of key-value pairs. Therefore, you need to use a mapped data structure that has named keys: something like `BTreeMap<String, _>`, `HashMap<String, _>`, or a struct.

> If I switch the params to use a struct instead everything works fine, which is why I know this is specifically an issue with enum serialization. Any ideas how to fix?

There is nothing to fix; this is working as intended.